# Stop square reader from disabling contactless after 20 seconds

Tags: ios, sdk, square, contactless-smartcard

I'm building an IOS POS app using the `square reader` and `SDK`, I would like it to work like a ticket machine on the bus with a preset amount always ready for a card to be presented. I've integrated the SDK and can preset the amount and launch the `Square POS` ready to take the payment however after about 20 seconds the reader goes to sleep and it has to be re-enabled manually by pressing the 're-enable contactless' on the screen. Do you know of a way to control this behavior so that the reader is always ready or at least wakes up when a card is presented without having to intervene manually?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to control reader sleep states at this time.